# Scrollable and zoom options in the Codename One Simulator

Tags: codenameone

Can you please explain me what is the difference of the two options "scrollable" and "zoom" of the Simulator? I've done some trials and they seems to act equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom used to have a different meaning. Right now it maps to disabling/enabling scrolling and sizing the window to a reasonable size.

We kept the menu option in place since people are used to that and `Scrollable` isn't an intuitive name.